# Confusion with universal references

Tags: c++, c++11

I have this code:

```
void f2(int& lvalue)
{
  std::cout <<"lvalue\n";
}
void f2(int&& rvalue)
{
  std::cout << "rvalue\n";
}

template<typename T>
void f(T&& param)
{
  f2(param);
}
```

I expect to get "lvalue" if I call *f* with:

```
int v = 10;
f(v);
```

and expect "rvalue" if I call *f* with:

```
f(10);
```

However, I always get the lvalue case. Please, can anybody explain where I'm wrong.

Comment: Related; http://stackoverflow.com/q/3582001/3747990

Answer (score 9):

You need to forward your parameter. Although the type of `param` could be an rvalue reference, `param` itself is still an lvalue.

```
f2(std::forward<T>(param));
```

`std::forward` ensures that `param` gets the same reference qualifier as the argument which was passed. This is known as *[perfect-forwarding](http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_07.html)*.

If you call `f(10)`:

- `param` is an lvalue
- `std::move(param)` is an rvalue
- `std::forward<T>(param)` in an rvalue

If you call `f(v)`:

- `param` is an lvalue
- `std::move(param)` is an rvalue
- `std::forward<T>(param)` in an lvalue

Comment: jus tested it and you're right! thank you, need time to think it over now